# Searching an element in a column and "print" it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'd like to search an element in a column and then use this element in a vlookup formula. My column contains either the same number (i.e : 2300) or nothing (""), but I have 26 different possible number (each number = a company).

I'd like to avoid VBA if possible

Example:

File 1.xlsx, COL A:
""
"2300"
"2300"
""
"2300"
"2300"
...

File 2.xlsx, COL A:
""
"1200"
""
"1200"
"1200"
"1200"
...

So if I'm the File 1.xlsx, I'd like to do the following : "If find something different than "", then print the number".

Hope I'm being clear. Thanks for your help in advance!

Jean

Comment: So to clarify... you're trying to find if a file contains a number that doesnt belong? Are you happy to modify the formula in each file, so that it knows which is the "correct" number to ignore, or are you wanting a formula that tries to figure out which number is the correct number and then returns the invalid number. Also, if there is more than 1 invalid number, are you happy for the formula to show only 1 invalid number at a time?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a vlookup on this kind of data. The value you're looking for must be in column sorted in alphabetical order, then from that, you can retrieve the value present in a cell present on the same line.

If you only want to test if the cell in empty, you could do simply this

```
=IF(<your cell>="";<you other cell>;"")
```

Be careful of relative and absolute coordinates.

Comment: Hello LuTo and thank you. I thought of that yes, but I have to use a little bit of VBA to sort my datas (I want it end user friendly). If there is not any other solution I'll go for that.

Answer (score 0):

This formula will return the first non-blank value that doesn't match 2300 in the range A1:A10. Update the range (in all 3 places) as required, and replace 2300 when searching for different values.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,MATCH(1,($A$1:$A$10<>"")*($A$1:$A$10<>2300),0))
```

Note this is an array entered formula. To enter it correctly, you need to double click into a cell so that you're in edit mode, paste the formula then confirm it by pressing `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`